GitLab EE: How to restrict non root users from creating projects?
We are using self hosted GitLab version 17.3.1 on our VM (Ubuntu 20.04). As per our company standards, we need no users (other than the root user) to create projects of any level (Private/Internal/Public). How can we achieve this?
We tried to select all the options of Restricted visibility levels under Visibility and access controls section in Admin General Settings page. But, we cannot restrict the Users from creating private projects.

Is ther any way we could implement this? or are there any other alternate options like hiding the New project/repository menu item for non Admin users?
